# URL parameters in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to access an id from a URL

http://localhost:8080/CI4/public/details/1

Routes.php

```
$routes->get('details/(:any)', 'Car::details/$1')
```

Car.php  (controller)

```
class Car extends BaseController
{

    public function details($id)
    {
        $carsModel = new carsModel();
        $query = $carsModel->findAll();

        

        $data = [
            'title_meta' => view('partials/title-meta', ['title' => 'Cars']),
            'page_title' => view('partials/page-title', ['title' => 'Vehicles', 'li_1' => 'Home', 'li_2' => 'Cars']),
            'carsList' => $query
        ];

        return view('details', $data);
    }
```

Partials head where css is referenced

```
    <!-- preloader css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/preloader.min.css" type="text/css" />

<!-- Bootstrap Css -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" id="bootstrap-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Icons Css -->
<link href="assets/css/icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- App Css-->
<link href="assets/css/app.min.css" id="app-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

i can get the ID on details page , but the CSS and page layout not loading
and the url become like this

http://localhost:8080/CI4/public/details/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
instead of
http://localhost:8080/CI4/public/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: use `php spark serve` to run the apps, and set the correct base url in `.env` file

Comment: CodeIgniter v4.1.1 Command Line Tool - Server Time: 2022-09-26 06:09:11 UTC-05:00

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type:        ErrorException
Message:     filter_var(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($options) of type array|int is deprecated
Filename:    C:\xampp\htdocs\CI4\system\HTTP\RequestTrait.php
Line Number: 326

Comment: How have you referenced the stylesheets in the partial templates. Can you update your question and include the parts of your partials where bootstrap css is referenced?

Comment: <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" id="bootstrap-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->request->uri->getSegment(3)` as what showed in the docs https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/incomingrequest.html#the-request-url.

and for

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: ErrorException Message: filter_var(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($options)

error, you need to check the php version also php.ini file. delete
`;` for some extension like `mbstring, openssl, gd` and make sure the
`extension_dir` is not commented by deleted `;` before it. If error
still occurs, update your composer.